# Is the chrome.fileSystem app API deprecated?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I thought I heard a rumor that the chrome.fileSystem app API is going to be deprecated in Chrome in the near future. I already searched Google but could find nothing about it. Does anyone know what the status is on this API and whether I can expect to be able to use in the future?

Comment: No, only the web sandboxed filesystem is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I missed seeing the announcement at the top of the Chrome Apps pages until after I posted this question.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index

> Chrome will be removing support for Chrome Apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

This will be completed in the spring of 2018. The app store will stop showing apps in the fall of 2017.