# With Chrome Apps soon to be removed, is there another way to edit a local file?

Tags: google-chrome-app

The Chrome Apps API has the very useful FileSystem API which allows a user to select a file for an app to edit (read and write changes to). However, with the entire Apps API soon to be removed, what other ways exists to edit a file on the local file system?

This is not an opinion-based question, I am asking for all conceivable alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912056/access-local-files-using-a-google-chrome-extension

Comment: Are you certain this API is being removed? 40 minutes ago it was "a rumor" in your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924438/is-the-chrome-filesystem-app-api-deprecated

Comment: Is it not? That was until I realized that the apps were what was being deprecated, not the fileSystem api.

Comment: You should answer your other question with that information, then, with the reputable source you found to back it up.

Comment: Done! I would dearly love for that question to not distract from this question, since this question stands on its own two feet.

Comment: The answer to that question leads you to the answer to this question, via the [migration guide](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration). "Q: My app uses the chrome.fileSystem API to read and write user-specified files and / or directories. Can this be done on the open web?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration:

> **Q: My app uses the chrome.fileSystem API to read and write user-specified files and / or directories. Can this be done on the open web?**
>
> A: In general, no. The open web can read single files that the user opens, but cannot retain access to those files, write to those files, or have any access to directories.
>
> If it is critical for your app to read and write directories (e.g. it is a text editor with a folder view), you will need to either have a native helper app and extension combo, or create a native app.